# batch - create directories from file names and copy these files in those directories

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a lot of (50 000+) files in a folder. They are named as: "abc_012345678_abcabc.ext"

I need to create a directory for each of this file (all in one different directory), named as the "number part" (012345678) and then copy this file to this directory.

So in the end, i have 50000+ directories, called like "265415873" , "654879623" and so on and inside each directory is the filename with matching name (so in dir 265478951 is file called abc_265478951_abcabc.ext).

Big thanks for any advice!

EDIT:
I already created a simple script, that does what I need, so if anyone is interested, here it is:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%f in (*.ext) DO (
  set filename=%%f
  set folder=!filename:~0,-4!
  set copypath=e:\work\programy\adresare_handa\adresare\!folder!
  mkdir !folder!
  copy !filename! !copypath!
)
pause
```

In this case, I only delete the extension and use the whole name of the file for the name of the directory, but I know, how to alter it, to read just the part of the file I need.

Thanx a lot again, if anyone have any comment for my version (pros/cons), please, do enlighten me :)

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

```
   @echo off
   pushd "C:\some_dir" 
   for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=_" %%A in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do (
      md "%%~B"
      copy %%A_%%B_%%C %%B
    )
```

only in case all files are with name pattern like `"abc_012345678_abcabc.ext"`